# jquery autocomplete sends empty get value to php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

i am very new to jquery n javascript. I am trying to make an autocomplete feature. I am using a sample code from a diff page to do this. but the 'term' it passes to the php page is empty. so the autocomplete doesnt work. I dont understand why, can someone take a look? I didnt change the labels but i am just trying to test it to see if it works. the issue is with the php page, the request 'term' is empty.

```
<head>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#txtLanguage" ).autocomplete({
            source: "source.php",
            minLength: 1 // how many character when typing to display auto complete
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="Language">Language: </label>
    <input id="txtLanguage" class="txtLanguage"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

include 'dbconnect.php';



    $q=$_REQUEST['term'];

    echo $q;

    $return = array();
   $stat="SELECT email FROM users WHERE email LIKE '$q'";
   $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$stat);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['email'],'value'=>$row['email']));
    }
    echo(json_encode($return));



?>
```

Comment: Is this page name "search.php"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:

```
 $stat="SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` LIKE '$q%'";
```

You forgot for % symbol and LIKE without % is equal to `email = '$q'`

Comment: oki, so here is what happened, i changed it and now it is displaying all the email values, all of them BUT NOT IN THE HTML PAGE but in the source.php. I just echoed them just to see if it works. the $q is still empty but I think the JSON thingy is displaying

Comment: All this source in one file?

Comment: You need to split it into 2 files: php and html.
Put `var_dump($_GET);` and look what variables is here.

Comment: i think i misunderstood what u asked, it is split into 2 separate files. Wht i mean earlier is that, they are both uploaded to the same directory.

Comment: put `var_dump ($_GET)` and show what it prints when you made ajax request to source.php

Comment: array(0) { } [{"label":"kum","value":"kum"},{"label":"Kumsan","value":"Kumsan"},{"label":"ryan","value":"ryan"},{"label":"san","value":"san"}]    this is what it gives   @DBuTbKa

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, the file path is correct? Is there any javascript error in the console?

1. Try console `$( "#txtLanguage" )`.
2. Remove source.php and add an array

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Use $_GET['term'] instead of $_REQUEST['term']

Comment: `$_REQUEST` automatically contains everything in `$_GET` and `$_POST` (unless you disable that PHP feature).

Comment: @KumaresanSandran It's controlled by the `request_order` option in `php.ini`.

Comment: @KumaresanSandran See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order